# Read file until certain character (BufferedReader)

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Here's my code which is not working:

```
try 
{
    while ((line1 = br.readLine()).substring(6).equals(name)) 
    {
        text = text + line1; 
        //text = text + '\n';
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I am trying to do is to read a text from a text file:

```
Name: Thailand.jpg.
Brief: This is Pattaya
Info: Nice city you know

Name: Austria.jpg
Brief: This is Austria
Info: Schwarzenegger was born here
```

Now I want to set only "This is Austria" text. But not able to.

Thank you!

Comment: so you only want to get the string "This is Austria" from the file?

Comment: This line `while ((line1 = br.readLine()).substring(6).equals(name)) {` is a mess.  Separate into readable logic.  Also what is `name`?  Why `substring(6)` ?

Comment: name is Austria. I need text from where it is Austria.

Comment: So what is your question? NB You need to test the result of `readLine()` for null before doing anything else with it. This code will throw `NullPointerException` at end of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I am not sure what are you going to do here. @Rod_Algonquin asked the question what I have too.`you only want to get the string "This is Austria" from the file?`, But you didn't provide any comment for that.

Assuming you are going to do something similar to that, you can try as follows.

```
           try {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
                          new FileReader(new File("/home/ruchira/Test.txt")));
            String line;
            String text = "";
            try {
                while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                       if(line.contains("Austria.jpg")){
                           String line1=br.readLine();
                           if(line1!=null){
                               text=text+line1.split(": ")[1];
                           }
                       }
                }
                System.out.println(text);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your substring index is wrong. Please re-calculate it. Also, you will have to check for null pointer condition. You should change you while loop condition as:

```
try 
{    
    while((line1=br.readLine())!=null && line1.substring(8).equals(name))
    {
        text = text + line1; 
        //text = text + '\n';
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

While calculating the index, you should also take white spaces  into consideration. Because of this, your required substring index becomes 8 and NOT 6.